# Difference between row with certain value (0) and next row in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for a way to program that my script searches for the 0 Stock in a unique product ID and calculates the difference between the dates of the next rows.

```
ID   Stock    Date
1      1      2010-12-05
1      0      2010-12-09
1      1      2010-12-16
1      3      2015-12-30
2      10     2015-01-05
2      0      2015-03-07
2      2      2015-03-27
2      0      2015-05-01
2      6      2015-05-10
3      4      2010-05-05
3      3      2017-02-02
3      0      2017-04-05
```

I want to calculate the percentage of time the product ID has a stock 0.

1. Product 1 is on average 7/25 days out of stock.

   - Out of stock #ID1: 2010-12-16 - 2010-12-09 = 7 days
   - Total time in stock #ID1: 2015-12-30 - 2010-12-05 = 25 days.
2. The second #ID2, is two times out of stock (29 days).
3. For the third #ID you want to take the sys.date() when it ends with a 0, so that one is from 2017-04-05 till 2017-04-13 (today).

Please can anybody help me, I prefer to use the dplyr package. I tried different approaches but I could not find a solution (group_by-->if.else(stock == 0) etc.)

Comment: 2015-12-30 - 2010-12-05 isn't 25 days, it's 1840 days (skip from 2010 to 2015). Is that intentional?

Comment: No was not intentional! It had to be 2010-12-30, but makes not a big difference in the idea of the question. Thank you very much for you answer!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by grouping by ID, using dplyr's `lead()` function to create a `Time` column with the amount of time in each state, then `summarize`:

```
library(dplyr)

d %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Time = as.integer(lead(Date, default = Sys.Date()) - Date)) %>%
  summarize(PercentZero = sum(Time[Stock == 0]) / sum(Time))
```

On your data, this results in:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
     ID PercentZero
  <int>       <dbl>
1     1  0.00378174
2     2  0.23200000
3     3  0.00000000
```

Note that the reason the first value is as low as `.0037` is that there's a four year gap from `2010-12-16` to `2015-12-30`

Answer (score 1):

Group by ID, use lead to subtract from the next date, fix the NAs, then summarise using first and last for the total.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date),
         out = ifelse(Stock == 0, lead(Date) - Date, 0),
         out = ifelse(is.na(out), Sys.Date() - Date, out)) %>% 
  summarise(out = sum(out),
            total = last(Date) - first(Date),
            fract = out / total)
```

Gives:

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 × 4
>      ID   out     total       fract
>   <int> <dbl>    <time>       <dbl>
> 1     1     7 1851 days 0.003781740
> 2     2    29  125 days 0.232000000
> 3     3     8 2527 days 0.003165809
> ```